# When a date is Entered the Macro will run

Tags: excel, vba, date, email

How do I add the code that will run automatically when a date is entered.  If the code includes other cells - do they need to be populated first.  The idea is when today's date is entered and email will be sent.  The code Email works but I need for the code to run automatically.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If IsDate(Range("A1").Value) Then
    'MsgBox "Plase enter a date in A1"
    'response = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo)
    'If response = vbYes Then
    email
Else
End If
'End If
End Sub


Sub email()

Dim r       As Range
Dim cell    As Range

Set r = Range("A1:S20")

For Each cell In r

    If cell.Value = Date Then

        Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, _
            Email_Cc, Email_Bcc, Email_Body As String
        Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant

        Email_Subject = Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value
        Email_Send_From = "Jean@test.com"
        Email_Send_To = "Joe@test.com"
        Email_Cc = ""
        Email_Bcc = ""
        Email_Body = "Hi " & Cells(cell.Row, "c").Value _
                     & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                     Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value & _
                     " has been submited"

        On Error GoTo debugs
        Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
        With Mail_Single
            .Subject = Email_Subject
            .To = Email_Send_To
            .cc = Email_Cc
            .BCC = Email_Bcc
            .Body = Email_Body
            .send
        End With

    End If

Next


Exit Sub

debugs:
If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want. When the value in `A1` is updated, it will first validate if the entry is a date. If entry is not a valid date, you will receive the first `MsgBox` in code.

If the entry *is* a valid date, the user will be asked if they want to send the email. If they select `No`, the macro will end. If they select `Yes`, your Email Sub will begin to execute.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Response As String

If Not IsDate(Range("A1").Value) Then
    MsgBox "Plase enter a valid date in A1"
Else
    Response = MsgBox("Do you want to send email?", vbYesNo)
    If Response = vbYes Then Call Email
End If

End Sub
```

If you do not want the user to have to choose `Yes` or `No` to send the email, and you want it to happen as soon as the entry in `A1` has been validated as a date, then change your IF statement to this:

```
If Not IsDate(Range("A1").Value) Then
    MsgBox "Plase enter a valid date in A1"
Else
    Call Email
End If
```

---

### Side Note

You should also update this to only execute when a certain range (or maybe individual cell in this case) is changed. Otherwise, the macro will fire when ANY cell is changed. Instead, determine the range that should trigger this macro, and then call the macro when the changed cell overlaps (or `Intersects`) with your pre-determined range.

Comment: Thank you. I will apply and comment back.

Comment: I took out the question and am using the second solution that works great.